# Display button only if ng-content isnt empty

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-content, angular-content-projection

I've been reading alot and to be honest haven't seen any meaningful solution.
So i have a component which contains a button and a dropdown to display some content (another buttons in this scenario).

Kebab button component:

```
<button>some button displaying dropdown<button>

<app-dropdown-component>
<ul>
<ng-content></ng-content>
</ul>
</app-dropdown-component>
```

It looks like this. As ng-content i'm providing a list items in a different components.
The thing is that i want to hide this button when no list items are provided.
Have tried using #ref on a  item and then

```
@ViewChild('ref') items: ElementRef;
```

and then check in ngAfterViewInit

```
this.showButton = this.items.nativeElement && this.items.nativeElement.children.length > 0
```

also with .detectChanges();

but it usually says 'cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.
Is there any simple way to hide my button when there are no elements provided by ng-content?
Also i can't use *ngIf on my button so looking for a different way.
I could also accept an solution from a children perspective:

```
<app-kebab-button-component>
<li *ngIf="something">Something</li>
</app-kebab-button-component>
```

So i show kebab-button-component only if there is any `<li>` provided due to a *ngIf statement.

Im running angular 12

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this with CSS:

```
app-dropdown-component{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

app-dropdown-component ul:empty ~ button {
  display: none;
}
```

While reversing the order of the items and button with `display: flex` and `flex-direction` as `row-reverse` or `column-reverse`.

```
<app-dropdown-component>
  <ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ul>

  <button>some button displaying dropdown<button>
</app-dropdown-component>
```

Comment: Went for a css solution but it seems like it targets these ng-content 'comments' so it isnt being marked as empty, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your ng-content component:

```html
<ng-content #ref></ng-content>
```

Otherwise ViewChild doesn't know what it's looking for.

Personally, I avoid ViewChild whenever possible.  Instead attach the *ngIf to the data that the content is bound to:

```html
<button *ngIf="items.length > 0">

<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course i've been using #ref tag on my <ul> actually, not on a <ng-content> forgot to mention that, but anyways im getting 'cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') while i try to console log it in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: See the second part of my answer.  I'd forget about NativeElement and bind your logic to the data.